# Is there any official SQL CE 4.0 samples?

Tags: sql-server

I can't seem to find any official SQL CE 4.0 samples? Can't find them on MSDN, TechNet or anywhere else...

Any ideas?

Comment: sample of.. database? tutorial? documentation? help? ctp (software)?

Answer (score 1):

Download and run [Visual Studio 2010 SP1 Tools for SQL Server Compact 4.0 ENU](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=212219). This likely requires SP1 installed for VS 2010.

When you run `SSCEVSTools-ENU.msi`, it'll include a sample on disk - Northwind.sdf.

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\v4.0\Samples\Northwind.sdf